# How WSO2 API Manager distributed setup works

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

How the process of deployment of api into GW node happens after publishing API from Publisher node in WSO2 APIM in a distributed set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a section called `<Environments>` under `<APIGateway>` in api-manager.xml configuration file. It is where the Gateway Environment section of an API is populated from in Publisher webapp. When you select an environment from that and publish from the Publisher webapp, it will create the Synapse artifact related to API and push it to Gateway by doing an Admin service call. For that `<ServerURL>` is used. So you need to correctly define the URL `<ServerURL>` in Publisher node so that it points to the GW node.